# calling the render method in single file components using Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue component which has a custom render method. The method is not getting called however.

```
<template>
  <div class="guide"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'guide',
  render: function(createElement){
    return createElement('div', 'this will never get called?'),
  },
};
</script>
```

I've looked through the documentation on single file components but it makes no reference to any caveats regarding render(). Is there another way to call this method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As ABDEL-RHMAN suggested, removing the template will cause the code to work; the `<template>` causes the render method to be ignored. Working example:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'guide',
  render: function(createElement){
    return createElement('div', 'this will get called?'),
  },
};
</script>
```